# How I do create a animated loading indicator spotify apps

Tags: spotify

How I do use the loading_indicator.png provided in the design resources folder to make it act like an ajax loader?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I display a loading indicator when starting my app, taken from the 'home' application (What's New). In your index.html:

```
<div class="loading">
  <div class="throbber"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

In you app.css:

```
@import url("sp://import/css/eve.css");
```

adam.css being the dark Spotify theme and eve.css the light. Then, when your application is finished loading, just remove the element. You can do it with the dom methods in the spotify dom.js. In your app.js:

```
var dom = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/dom');

var loadingEl = dom.queryOne('.loading');
dom.destroy(loadingEl);
```

I don't know if the dom.js will be in the official API or not. Otherwise you can remove it any other way (standard dom methods, other js libraries you're using, etc):

```
var loadingEl = document.querySelector('.loading');
loadingEl.parentNode.removeChild(loadingEl);
```

Note that the above example does not necessarily use the loading_indicator.png but whatever images that are used by the adam.css and eve.css themes.

If you wan't to use the loader as a normal ajax loading indicator inside your app, then all the normal rules of web apps apply. Display loader when initiating ajax call, hide it in completed-callback, position it with css.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old topic, but with the 1.X API there is an easier way to do this by [using the Throbber class](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/throbber-throbber.html) which allows you to instantiate and hide fairly simply via JS.

```
var tracks = document.getElementById('tracks');
var throbber = Throbber.forElement(tracks);
// (wait for tracks to load and render)
throbber.hide();
```

Just make sure to include the Throbber class at the beginning of your JS:

```
require([
  '$views/throbber#Throbber'
], function (Throbber) {
```